# App doesn't swing 8th and dotted quarter, but does swing dotted quarter + 8th

Tags: rhythm, swing

I've started to learn swing 8th rhythm and I think I understand the idea when it comes to pairs of 8th. But how to read the pairs of "dotted quarter + 8th".

I'm using the app to insert and play the rhythm and I noticed the following.

1. Let's say we are in 4/4 and bar contains
   ***8th + dotted quarter + 8th + dotted quarter***
   The rhythm sounds the same when I change from "straight 8th" to "swing 8th" mode.
2. But if I change the bar to
   ***dotted quarter + 8th + dotted quarter + 8th***
   Now the rhythm sounds different when I change from "straight 8th" to "swing 8th" mode.

I expected rhythm to change in both bars (1 and 2). Why is the first case swing 8th = straight 8th, but in the second case the are not equal?

Any help will be appreciated, tnx.

EDIT: app is called Complete Rhythm Trainer (on Android).

Comment: This is possibly specific to the app you're using. What happens if, rather than 8th + dotted quarter, you use 8th + 8th-tied-to-quarter?

Comment: Swing can often be just a 'feel' thing, almost impossible to get computer playback to make it feel good from a score. Sometimes it's just written straight, with 'swing' written over the first bar.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks, yes when I use 8th-tied-to-quarter instead of dotted quarter it changes.

Comment: Cool. I suggest editing your question to include the software you're using. That will help future searchers.

Comment: @cartoflur9 It might be helpful for future readers to know what software you are using, in case they are trying to find out the same issue. **EDIT** Ha, jinx.

Comment: Trouble is, swing is a human feel, and will vary player to player, song to song. There is no accurate, specific, division to the beats that equal 'swing', so any app will just give a close approximation. Which often ends up as a 12/8 version of 4/4. Which is always a good start point, but anything more 'mechanical' will sound just so.

Comment: @Neal Do I have to buy you a Coke now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It theory, you should hear a "swing" in both cases, so this may be software-specific. Try changing the ***8th + dotted quarter*** notation to ***8th + 8th-tied-to-quarter***. That might nudge your software into recognizing the intended swing rhythm.

Answer (score 1):

The examples below show how the two rhythms you mention (top staff) should be played with swing (bottom staff), assuming the popular triplet realization of swing rhythm.
[image]

If your software plays it differently, it's incorrect. If you want to play straight eight notes in a piece with swing feel, you should write it explicitly.

Comment: Yeah, I also expected that. Actually as @Aaron suggested this is the app issue. When I change dotted quarter to 8th-tied-to-quarter I work as displayed in the second line ^. Thanks anyway.

Comment: +1 Notating this way obviates any issues the software might have with swing rhythm. Harder for a human reader, though, IMO.

Comment: @Aaron Agreed. The top staff is for a human reader who is supposed to know whether they want to swing it and how. The bottom staff is for demonstration purposes only.

Comment: Actually, your post makes that abundantly clear. user1079505's post: 1; Aaron's reading comprehension: 0.

Comment: @Aaron misunderstandings are not unexpected in human readers ;)

Comment: Touché. Thou cuteth to the bone.